# Copy Range From One Sheet Paste Part of Range In Same Sheet Based On Cell Value On Another Sheet

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, named-ranges

Right now I've created a code to copy values from one range to another range based on the value from another sheet (the copy and paste happens on one sheet).

But because this value can be one of twelve values, the range that is being copied and pasted becomes smaller.

Because I'm not adept at VBA I created dozens of copy ranges and dozens of paste ranges in Excel to handle ElseIf statements via VBA to copy and paste depending on what the cell value is in the other sheet.

I'm curious, is there a way to make my code more optimized and have less named ranges in my workbook?

Any help would be appreciated, here's my code pasted below (each named range for both the copy and paste is simply one less column due to what the selections can be in the first sheet):

```
SubTest()

If ws0.Range("D6") = "BUD" Then    
    ws1.Range("CopyFormulasFT").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ws1.Range("PasteFormulasFT").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

ElseIf ws0.Range("D6") = "F01" Then
    ws1.Range("CopyFormulasFTOneEleven").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ws1.Range("PasteFormulasFTOneEleven").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

ElseIf ws0.Range("D6") = "F02" Then
    ws1.Range("CopyFormulasFTTwoTen").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ws1.Range("PasteFormulasFTTwoTen").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

ElseIf ws0.Range("D6") = "F03" Then
    ws1.Range("CopyFormulasFTThreeNine").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ws1.Range("PasteFormulasFTThreeNine").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

ElseIf ws0.Range("D6") = "F04" Then
    ws1.Range("CopyFormulasFTFourEight").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ws1.Range("PasteFormulasFTFourEight").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

ElseIf ws0.Range("D6") = "F05" Then
    ws1.Range("CopyFormulasFTFiveSeven").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ws1.Range("PasteFormulasFTFiveSeven").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

ElseIf ws0.Range("D6") = "F06" Then
    ws1.Range("CopyFormulasFTSixSix").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ws1.Range("PasteFormulasFTSixSix").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

ElseIf ws0.Range("D6") = "F07" Then
    ws1.Range("CopyFormulasFTSevenFive").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ws1.Range("PasteFormulasFTSevenFive").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

ElseIf ws0.Range("D6") = "F08" Then
    ws1.Range("CopyFormulasFTEightFour").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ws1.Range("PasteFormulasFTEightFour").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

ElseIf ws0.Range("D6") = "F09" Then
    ws1.Range("CopyFormulasFTNineThree").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ws1.Range("PasteFormulasFTNineThree").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

ElseIf ws0.Range("D6") = "F10" Then
    ws1.Range("CopyFormulasFTTenTwo").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ws1.Range("PasteFormulasFTTenTwo").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

ElseIf ws0.Range("D6") = "F11" Then
    ws1.Range("CopyFormulasFTElevenOne").Select
    Selection.Copy
    ws1.Range("PasteFormulasFTElevenOne").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you provide the addresses of at least two or three of ***both*** a Copy and a Paste named range? If there's a pattern, this will be very easy to optimize. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach, this one much more flexible and easier to update:

```
Sub CondCopy()

    Dim ws0 As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim str0 As String, str1 As String, str2 As String
    Dim strCond As String, ArrLoc As Long
    Dim strCopy As String, strPaste As String, strNum As String

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws0 = .Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set ws1 = .Sheets("Sheet2")
    End With

    str0 = ";One;Two;Three;Four;Five;Six;Seven;Eight;Nine;Ten;Eleven"
    str1 = ";Eleven;Ten;Nine;Eight;Seven;Six;Five;Four;Three;Two;One"
    str2 = "BUD;F01;F02;F03;F04;F05;F06;F07;F08;F09;F10;F11"
    strCond = ws0.Range("D6").Value

    ArrLoc = Application.Match(strCond, Split(str2, ";"), 0) - 1
    strNum = Split(str0, ";")(ArrLoc) & Split(str1, ";")(ArrLoc)

    strCopy = "CopyFormulasFT" & strNum
    strPaste = "PasteFormulasFT" & strNum

    With ws1
        .Range(strCopy).Copy
        .Range(strPaste).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, SkipBlanks:=True
    End With

End Sub
```

In the case that you need to add more named ranges following your pattern, just editing `str0`, `str1`, and `str2` is enough.

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: This above code is great, however when it pastes it pastes inverted, should only paste the columns to the right of the range, it's copying appropriately but not pasting appropriately within the range. Looking to see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Ah figured it out, was missing the strNum when I copied the above code, thank-you!

Comment: Question, I had another piece of code I was trying to manipulate using your above code however I keep getting the "Range of object worksheet failed" error.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. :) Kindly start a new question if it's a different code or problem from this one. :)

Comment: Just did here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21866608/copy-range-from-one-sheet-paste-part-of-range-in-same-sheet-with-multiplier-base Thanks BK201 :)

Answer (score 3):

Using string manipulation and a loop you could greatly reduce the size of that code:

```
dim arrStrings(1 to 11) as string
arrStrings(1) = "OneEleven"
arrStrings(2) = "TwoTen"
arrStrings(2) = "ThreeNine"
...
arrStrings(11) = "NineThree"

 dim  i as integer
    for i = 1 to 11
        If ws0.Range("D6") = "F"+ strings.trim(str(i)) Then
             ws1.Range("CopyFormulasFT" + arrStrings(i)).Select
             Selection.Copy
             ws1.Range("PasteFormulasFT" + arrStrigns(i)).Select
             Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
             SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
        end if
    next i
```

if the actual code is something like this

"oneone", "onetwo", "onethree", ..., "oneeleven", "twoone", "twotwo", "twothree", ... "twoeleven" ...

(11x11 strings)
you could use a double loop over this array:

```
dim arrStrings(1 to 11) as string
arrStrings(1) = "One"
arrStrings(2) = "Two"
arrStrings(2) = "Three"
...
arrStrings(11) = "Nine"
```

and you can create the string like this
Str = "CopyFormulasFT"+ arrstrings(i) + arrstrings(j)

Comment: I sincerely suggest editing the above before you get downvoted. As you can see, the range from where he's copying and where's he's pasting are from *different* sheets and have *different* names. Unless you edit the above strings to change along with your iterator `i`, this is not an applicable answer. I won't downvote, though, as the logic is very sound but the application is bit off.

Comment: Thanks did not see the different strings in there

Comment: +1: Actually, I was wrong with the different sheets, but indeed correct with the different names.

Answer (score 2):

> is there a way to make my code more optimized and have less named ranges in my workbook?

depends on how your data organized. But now, you can slightly simplify your code:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim destRng As String
    Dim sorceRng As String

    Select Case ws0.Range("D6")
        Case "BUD"
            sorceRng = "CopyFormulasFT": destRng = "PasteFormulasFT"
        Case "F01"
            sorceRng = "CopyFormulasFTOneEleven": destRng = "PasteFormulasFTOneEleven"
        Case "F02"
            sorceRng = "CopyFormulasFTTwoTen": destRng = "PasteFormulasFTTwoTen"
        Case "F03"
            sorceRng = "CopyFormulasFTThreeNine": destRng = "PasteFormulasFTThreeNine"
        Case "F04"
            sorceRng = "CopyFormulasFTFourEight": destRng = "PasteFormulasFTFourEight"
        Case "F05"
            sorceRng = "CopyFormulasFTFiveSeven": destRng = "PasteFormulasFTFiveSeven"
        Case "F06"
            sorceRng = "CopyFormulasFTSixSix": destRng = "PasteFormulasFTSixSix"
        Case "F07"
            sorceRng = "CopyFormulasFTSevenFive": destRng = "PasteFormulasFTSevenFive"
        Case "F08"
            sorceRng = "CopyFormulasFTEightFour": destRng = "PasteFormulasFTEightFour"
        Case "F09"
            sorceRng = "CopyFormulasFTNineThree": destRng = "PasteFormulasFTNineThree"
        Case "F10"
            sorceRng = "CopyFormulasFTTenTwo": destRng = "PasteFormulasFTTenTwo"
        Case "F11"
            sorceRng = "CopyFormulasFTElevenOne": destRng = "PasteFormulasFTElevenOne"
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
    End Select

    ws1.Range(sorceRng).Copy
    ws1.Range(destRng).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, SkipBlanks:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: +1: I have exactly this on my end as well, but I'm thinking about his line "reduce the named ranges" as well. If he doesn't have a pattern to his ranges, this is the best. Easy to maintain, as well.