# Automate copying data

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data in one sheet of excel. From that I want to find certain particular value from a column and then copy that row of value in new sheet.I there are multiple values in a column,then it will copy all those value. For Example in the image below. I want to find 409539 and all the rows corresponding to these values will be pasted in next sheet. I am using Excel Vba and used below code for reference but i am getting some error

```
For Each c In rngSearch
    If c.Value = SearchRange Then
        For Each K In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Search").Range("1:10")
            If K.Value = "" Then
                ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Search").K.Value = c.Value
            End If
        Next K
        Replace = c.Offset(0, 5).Value
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Search").Range("B2").Value = Replace
    End If
Next c
```

[image]

Comment: There are many answered questions about copying data from worksheet to worksheet, here's one https://stackoverflow.com/a/48560444/19179399, next time it will be wise to research a little more

Comment: What is the error that you get?